# Outlook VB Script: Outlook does not recognize one or more names

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I have the following script to run, which sends out an email acknowledgement from a template to external users that contact a shared mailbox.  About once or twice a week I encounter the error listed in the Title field.

Would you be able to assist in providing code that would ignore an email address it cannot resolve and, if possible, a message to notify me when this occurs?

Sorry, I set this up a couple of years ago and learned just enough to get this to work :/

---

```
Sub AutoReplywithTemplate(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oRespond As Outlook.MailItem

 ' Use this for a real reply
 ' Set oRespond = Item.Reply

 ' This sends a response back using a template
Set oRespond = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\dannygonzales\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\GMS Technical Support Email Acknowledgment (Default).oft")

With oRespond
 .Recipients.Add Item.SenderEmailAddress
 .Subject = "GMS Technical Support Acknowledgement"
 .HTMLBody = vbCrLf & oRespond.HTMLBody

 ' includes the original message as an attachment
 ' .Attachments.Add Item

' use this for testing, change to .send once you have it working as desired
 .Send
End With
Set oRespond = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Recipients.ResolveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recipients.resolveall.aspx) method; it will return False if there is a problem with any of the recipient's addresses.  You can evaluate Recipient.Resolved for each member of the collection to determine which one is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, Eric!  I appreciate the response!